# Is it possible to calculate column totals/sums within a python panel tabulator table?

Tags: python, panel, tabulator

I can't seem to find anywhere of anyone being able to do this.

I've search all of panel tabulator, and it seems that they reference maybe being able to do it using the tabulator api essentially, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `calcs` option in the Tabulator constructor by specifying which columns should have calculations applied to them and the type of calculation such as `sum`, `average`, `minimum`, `maximum`, etc.

```
import tabulator

# Load data into Tabulator
table = tabulator.Stream("data.csv")

# Specify calculation for a column
table.calcs("sum", columns=[{"field":"column_name", "title":"Column Total"}])

# Stream the data and display the table
table.stream().interactive()
```